# How can I calculate the CheckSum8 Xor in TwinCAT 3?

Tags: checksum, plc, twincat

I am working with commands like : `$02WSLD00000$03` and I know the checksum of this should be `=` ASCII character or `61` in decimal or `3D` in hexadecimal.
I am trying to use the `CRC_GEN` function from OSCAT library but it is not working at all. [This website](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/) is giving the correct value.

What can I do?

This is what I am trying now:

```
IF StartCheckSum THEN
    CommandARRAY := MAXSTRING_TO_BYTEARR(GVL_SERIAL.HexCommand1);
    CheckSumResult := CRC_GEN(
        ADR(GVL_SERIAL.HexCommand1), 
        SIZEOF(GVL_SERIAL.HexCommand1),
        16#1021, 16#8F, 16#0000, REV_IN, REV_OUT, 16#0000
    );
END_IF

StartCheckSum := FALSE;
```

Comment: Where are you getting the values for `PL`, `PN`, `INIT`, etc.? They don't match any of the listed options in the OSCAT documentation.

Comment: I've been trying different values from different sources. Tbh I don't really know about them

Answer (score 1):

The `CheckSum8 XOR` calculator in the web link you provided is simply XOR'ing all of the bytes of the input string together. If this is all you require, you could write a simple loop to churn this out from your input string.

These settings will produce the same output from `CRC_GEN`:

- `PL` = 8
- `PN` = 1
- `INIT` = 0
- `REV_IN` = FALSE
- `REV_OUT` = FALSE
- `XOR_OUT` = 0