# CheckSum8 Xor in TwinCAT 3

Tags: hex, ascii, checksum, plc, twincat

I need to calculate the **CheckSum8Xor** (like on this website: https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/) but on twinCAT3.

Working with strings like "$02WLEN00600$03" and then I need to add the checksum at the end of strings like these berore sending it to a JBC SFR B (soldering dispensor).

I am still trying to use the **CRC_GEN** from **OSCAT Library** with this configuration:

CheckSumResult_1:=CRC_GEN(ADR(GVL_SERIAL.HexCommand1),SIZEOF(GVL_SERIAL.HexCommand1),8,1,0,REV_IN,REV_OUT,0); //CheckSumResult_1 is DWORD

but this is not giving me the correct value like the website does.

I tried to use the CRC_GEN from OSCAT Library like this:

CheckSumResult_1 := CRC_GEN(ADR(GVL_SERIAL.HexCommand1),SIZEOF(GVL_SERIAL.HexCommand1),8,1,0,REV_IN,REV_OUT,0);

Example command: "$02WLEN00600$03" where it can go from 00000 to 99999

Comment: Did you put in the web page the string $02WLEN00600$03 in hexadecimal? Because in CODESYS the characters "$02" and "$03" are the second and third character in ASCII and the web page will understand 3 characters. In the first one dollar: cero and three

Answer (score 0):

You are asking essentially the same question you asked 3 months ago.
[How can I calculate the CheckSum8 Xor in TwinCAT 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75799749/how-can-i-calculate-the-checksum8-xor-in-twincat-3)

The `CRC_GEN` function in OSCAT **will** produce the same result as the `CheckSum8 Xor` calculation on the scadacore.com webpage, provided that you use the proper values for `PL`, `PN`, `INIT`, `REV_IN`, `REV_OUT`, and `XOR_OUT`. I have tested this in TwinCAT 3.

Most likely you are mixing up the use of ASCII and hexadecimal. Do you want the input data to be treated as individual ASCII characters (including the dollar signs)? If so, you have to make sure that `CRC_GEN` is reading a byte array that is made up the ASCII values of each of these characters. (Using a `STRING` datatype kind of takes care of this for you.) And you would need to make sure that you're comparing it against the same data entered in the `ASCII Input` field on the scadacore.com webpage.